# Sorting info from a txt file into two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, import

For a uni assignment, I have to take input from a text file and sort it into two separate arrays. The text file is a football league table, arranged as such:
Barcelona  34
Real Madrid  32

I have written a piece of code like this:

```
holdingString = fileInput.readLine ();                
StringTokenizer sort = new StringTokenizer (holdingString + " "); 
countOfTokens = sort.countTokens();
System.out.println (countOfTokens + " tokens: " + holdingString);
```

This prints out the number of tokens and what the tokens are for each line, so it gives output of
Two tokens:  Barcelona  34
Three tokens:  Real Madrid  32

I've then written this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countOfTokens; i++)
 {
  String temp = sort.nextToken ();          
  System.out.println(temp);
 }
```

This reads just the next token and prints it out.
However, rather than printing the next token out, I want to check if it is a word or a number, and separate it into a different array accordingly, so it will be like this:
ArrayTeam Zero Element Barcelona
ArrayTeam First Element Real Madrid
ArrayPoints Zero Element 34
ArrayPoints First Element 32

What's the easiest way to do this? I've tried using a try/catch, but didn't get it right. I've also tried using an if statement with \d, but that's not worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AmitD, I agree that using `split` is more appropriate in this case, but if you still like to use a `StringTokenizer` you do something like:

```
StringBuilder teamName=new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < countOfTokens-1; i++)
{
  if (i>0) teamName.append(' ');
  teamName.append(sort.nextToken());          
}
teamNames[k]=teamName.toString(); //add the new team to your teamNames array
points[k]=Integer.parseInt(sort.nextToken()); //if your points array is of int type
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I'm struggling adapting it to store "temp" in separate arrays, rather than printing out numbers. Do you have advice? (i.e. array 1 holding team names, array 2 holding the points)

Comment: Let's say in your updated example I change the arrays to this: teamNames[0] and points[0].    
My mind says that logically teamName[0] should now contain "Barcelona" (first team in text file). Similarly, points[0] should contain their points ("34")    

Instead, teamName is "Zaragoza" (the very last string in the file), and their number of points (8) is in the first element of points. Every other value in both arrays is null.

This is what I don't understand!!

Comment: @AndrewMartin After each processed line, you should increment the `k` variable. If you are using 0 it will insert the values on the same first position.

Comment: I kinda understand that, but I don't get why the first token stored in the array ISN'T the first token in the text file, but rather the very last token. This means that even when I increment the k variable, I'm still just getting nulls, as there's nothing left IN the text file.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I need to see your code, in order to answer this. I'm not sure if you are getting null values for all the entries except the last one. Or you are getting the last entry from the file, as the first element in the array?

Comment: The second one - I'm getting the last entry in the file as the first element in the array, with all other elements as null values.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Then you are not incrementing properly the `k` variable, or it's outside of your reading loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19025/discussion-between-dan-and-andrew-martin)

Comment: After learning how to properly structure my arrays, this answer worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save all that trouble using [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String strs[] = holdingString.split("\\s");
```

E.g.

```
"Barcelona 34".split("\\s"); will return you Array of Strings where 
 array[0]=Barcelona  array[1]=34
```

From Javadoc of [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

**Update**
As @madhairsilence pointed out
You need another deliminator. You  can use `=` like property files

```
"Real Madrid =34".split("=");//will return you Array of Strings where 
 array[0]=Real Madrid, array[1]=34
```

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) as you are reading from file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you tel me what the "\\s" actually means?

Comment: @AndrewMartin It is white space. Have a look at [Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: If the input is Real Madrib -> You algo will print just "Real" not "Real madrib"

Comment: @AmitD: I like the idea of using split, but am still not sure how to do it when input is from txt file. The input will look like "Real Madrid           32" and I need to know to separate out the spaces etc and store just the words and numbers in separate arrays

Comment: If you have to do it from file you can use `Scanner` which also accepts deliminator.Or just use whatever you are using and once you do read line use split and then get the array

Comment: @AmitD: So just to confirm, as I'm reading from the text file (and I can't change the text file to add deliminators), you would recommend using the Scanner class in combination with split? Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMartin Its either or. User Scanner or split whichever you like but `Scanner` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you could use java.util.Scanner class to read data from the file. it has methods such as nextInt(), nextDouble ...whhich might be useful in your case.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
int number;
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    number = scan.nextInt();
 }
```

check [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
String readLine = "Real Madrib 40";

        String[] team = readLine.split( "\\d" );        
        System.out.println(team[0]);

        String score = readLine.replace( team[0],"" );      
        System.out.println(score);
```

**Output :**

team[0] : Real Madrib

score : 40